# Непонятная проблема с загрузкой страницы под Российским IP (IMA SDK for HTML5)

Tags: javascript, сеть, ssl, cross-origin

Друзья, всем привет.

Крутим видео рекламу (VAST, VPAID). Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой, нужен совет, куда копать.

**Не большая вводная**
*Те, кто знаком с терминами VAST и VPAID могут пропустить.*

**VAST** - шаблон для XML файлов которые качает видеоплеер и понимает, какую видео рекламу ему показывать, как и куда сообщать о событиях (показ, клик, первая четверть ролика, вторая и т.п.). Если кому интересно [спецификация](https://iabtechlab.com/standards/vast/), [вот так](https://yandex.ru/ads/adfox/276021/getCode?p1=clnuy&p2=gera) выглядит простенький VAST.

Есть два основных типа рекламы

1. Видео - просто ссылка на видео файл, задача плеера выбрать подходящий формат, воспроизвести и отбить события.
2. Video Player-Ad Interface Definition (**VPAID**) - представляет из себя ссылку на JS бандл. Плеер создает для нее отдельный iframe, там инициализирует и кайфует. Он не знает что там дальше делает этот бандл (там может быть статика, видео реклама или JS игра какая-нибудь), а просто сидит и слушает команды (реклама началась, реклама закончилась и т.п.). Если от бандла давно нет вестей, то он дестроит фрейм и отправляется по VAST'у дальше, в поиске следующей рекламы. Если кому интересно вот [спецификация](https://iabtechlab.com/standards/video-player-ad-interface-definition-vpaid/).

**Проблема**
Плееров в которых крутят рекламу вагон и маленькая тележка. Кто-то пишет с нуля свои решения, кто-то использует готовые, как полностью с нуля написанные, так и частично в виде сторонних библиотек.

Чуть подробнее опишу, что делает плеер (наш, и многие другие) когда видит в VAST'e VPAID бандл. В целом всё сделано по спеке.

1. Вставляет на страницу `iframe` без адреса.
2. Вкрячивает (разными способами, мы через `contentWindow.document.write`) в него VPAID (js файлик). Ждет его загрузку и начинает с ним работать.
   Все работает годами, всё отлично.

Но, есть плееры, которые для воспроизведения VAST'ов используют библиотеку [IMA SDK for HTML5](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side) от гугла. Там инициализация VPAID происходит другим способом - `iframe` там инициализируется не пустой, а с адресом вида `https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/loader21.html?#VPAID_BUNDLE#`. Дальше, всё происходит так же, как и везде.

Дак вот проблема. Примерно две недели назад (мы заметили, возможно и раньше). Хром начал блокировать адрес `https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/loader21.html` с формулировкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Только с части российских IP адресов, по моим личным прикидкам 50 на 50. Если вы из России просто попробуйте открыть этот адрес во вкладке браузера и он с большой вероятностью не откроется.
2. Не важно какой там дальше бандл, блокируется именно этот адрес https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/loader21.html

Предположения.

1. Какие-то новые Privacy политики в гугл хроме. Тогда получается стрельнули себе в ногу? И почему только с российских IP адресов?
2. Роскомнадзор балуется? Но почему с части российских IP адресов работает. Да и в целом `tracert` до tpc.googlesyndication.com идёт.

Спасибо за идеи

**UPD:**

1. Забыл написать, что не открывается ни только в хроме. В целом в любом браузере.
2. Конечно, блокировщики рекламы отключены. Дефолтные браузеры с дефолтными настройками.

Comment: у меня браузер блокирует по фильтру ||googlesyndication.com^ - включена защита от отслеживания и два блокера рекламы. Проверьте ваши блокировки. И выясните у других, у кого блокируется, не включены ли блокеры.

Comment: Да, а на интерес переключитесь на ВПН евпропейский и обновите страницу. Хренак и всё загрузится.
Не у кого ничего не стоит. Дефолтный браузер.

Comment: Возможно у вас конкретно стоят блокаровщики рекламы, или еще что-то. Я давно в этом бизнесе :) и понимаю, что если что-то непонятное проихсодит, то первым делом надо проверить а не стоит ли каких-то блокировщиков. Щас про апдейчу пост.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в IP, используйте приватные зарубежные SOCKS5 прокси если на это сервере, либо прокси-реквест на клиенте. Сейчас в целом большие проблемы с доступом к ресурсам, рекламе и т.д. с российских IP. Те же картинки и аватарки у большинства пользователей в YouTube не грузятся, про ограничения по рекламе, монетизации для российских пользователей промолчу.

Comment: Конкретно у нас всё отлично, мы этой библиотекой не пользуемся. Проблемы у тех, кого мы крутим там, глубже в VPAID бандлах. У них там свои плееры, VAST'ы и VPAID бандлы. Цепочка, теоритически, может уходить очень глубоко. И что и кто там за 10 Iframe'мами открыл мы контролировать не можем. Но видим, что происходит беда. Задача треда понять, почему это происходит и написать хорошие письма партнерам, в которых подробно описать проблему, с причинами, а не просто сказать: "Происходит неведомая еб*нина".

Comment: Ну понять весь этот бред трудно, но сам факт, что траст российских IP упал до нуля, соответственно иногда даже в целях безопасности могут блокироваться российские IP (привет российским хакерам). Что конкретно произошло сможет ответить только Google, если трассировка до ресурса идет, но они не снизойдут до такого 100%. У меня кстати с российских IP идет ошибка "Connection refused", а так сайты любят обычно блокировать доступ к себе. В любом случае решение проблемы достаточно легкое - использование прокси :)

curl: (7) Failed to connect to tpc.googlesyndication.com port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Можно найти российский сервер (который хостится в РФ) с зарубежными на нем IP и проверить наличие проблемы, чтобы определить так как сказать ее корни, потому что возможно даже не Google виноват, а какие-то внутренние блокировки на магистралях в связи с санкциями, отключением зарубежного ПО и т.д. Но тут нужна будет выборка скорее всего как минимум из нескольких серверов, поэтому от затеи полностью разобраться в проблеме скорее всего придется отказаться и довольствоваться нашими мыслями :) Возможно кто-то еще сможет что сказать на эту тему, но это все будет из разряда "мне кажется...".